# Get id value from Datatable button

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a `datatable` in my project which works perfectly, in the last column I'm adding a button for each row which also works fine.

I'm assigning a specific value to the `id` attribute of this button and trying now to get that value when clicking on the button but I didn't manage to get that

Any suggestions please?

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable();
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var id = table.row($(this).attr('id'));
            console.log(id);
        });
```

but the above code returns:

> [0: Array[0], context: Array[1], selector: Object, ajax: Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'id' attribute assigned to your `button` use this;

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable();
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //$(this) refers the clicked button element
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks!, worked perfectly, and sorry about my poor knowledge as I'm new to this and still confused about some of these stuff